# Map multiple columns simultaneously with different maps

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas data frame here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','a','b','b'],
                   'col2': ['a','a','b','b']})
```

I have a mapping dictionary here:

```
dict_map = {'col1': {'a': 0.5, 'b': 1.0},
            'col2': {'a': 0.6, 'b': 0.9}}
```

I want to map each column with the corresponding dictionary so that the data frame will look like:

```
    col1  col2
0   0.5   0.6
1   0.5   0.6
2   1.0   0.9
3   1.0   0.9
```

I can easily iterate through the columns in `df` and achieve the desired result, but I am trying to avoid iterating. How can I do this without iterating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```py
df = df.replace(dict_map)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2
0   0.5   0.6
1   0.5   0.6
2   1.0   0.9
3   1.0   0.9
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `df.replace(dict)` function to avoid loops.