# Replace other values with np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2],
                  'col2': [4,5]})
```

I have a replacement dictionary:

```
dict_replace = {
    'col1': {1:'a', 2:'b'},
    'col2': {4:'c', 5:'d'}
}
```

I can easily replace the values in `X` using:

```
X = X.replace(dict_replace)
```

Resulting in:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b'],
                  'col2': ['c','d']})
```

However, if a new value appears in `X` which is not in `dict_replace` (for the respective column) I want it replaced with `np.nan`.

For example, a data frame:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3],
                  'col2': [4,5,7]})
```

Should look like:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b',np.nan],
                  'col2': ['c','d',np.nan]})
```

What are some ways I can do this without having to iterate?

Comment: Good evening, @Aaron! Didn't I answer [a previous question of yours?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69967259/17242583) :) Hi again!

Comment: Any particular reason you're converting int64 dtype columns to object dtype? You're losing out on all the benefits of vectorization.

Comment: @ddejohn just to communicate the example easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), which, though only available on columns, can be used on the whole dataframe with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
X = X.apply(lambda col: col.map(dict_replace[col.name]))
```

Output:

```
>>> X
  col1 col2
0    a    c
1    b    d
2  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `mask`

```
out = X.replace(dict_replace).mask(lambda x : x==X)
Out[215]: 
  col1 col2
0    a    c
1    b    d
2  NaN  NaN
```